# How do I uninstall paper theme from my computer?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, uninstall, themes, icon-themes

I installed this them from the site:

https://snwh.org/paper

But it's been giving me trouble and  making my computer slow. How do I uninstall the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall the 'paper' theme remove the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove paper-icon-theme paper-gtk-theme paper-cursor-theme
```

If you have used the provided PPA you can safely remove the PPA  with ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:snwh/pulp
```

**References:**

- [Ask Ubuntu: How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/57576)